# Changing the height of one row in the month view in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm not looking for the height of every row in my month view in FullCalendar to be the exact same height; I just want to be able to see the full content of every cell in the calendar.

```
contentHeight: 'auto'
```

doesn't appear to solve anything in this view, and adjusting the `contentHeight` to a specific integer adjusts all rows evenly, which makes the calendar unnecessarily huge if it's just one particular cell, and thus row, that needs to be bigger to display all events.

Additionally, it appears that I'd have to figure out how big to set `contentHeight` in a fairly complicated manner, as 'auto' doesn't appear to make adjustments for additional events on one particular date.

It's easy to reproduce by adding around 10 events to one date, and setting contentHeight to 'auto'.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you expected [contentHeight](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight) to help you in this case, since the documentation makes clear that this affects the whole calendar area, not just individual rows.

You haven't made it entirely clear, but it sounds like you're trying to deal with a scenario where you have a lot of events on one particular day, and would like the calendar to expand the height of that row so they are all visible.

As far as I can observe, the calendar will do this for you by default. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7nsbjya5/1/ . There are 9 events all on one day, and no events elsewhere in the month. The row on which the events occur is automatically expanded to accommodate them.

The only way I can see where this would not happen is if you had set the [eventLimit](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit) value to something other than its default.

e.g. if you set

```
eventLimit: 3
```

then the calendar will never display more than 3 events in any cell, and will replace the others with a link where they are then displayed in a popover when clicked.

Whereas, if, as per my demo, if you either do not set `eventLimit`, or set it to

```
eventLimit: false
```

(which is the default anyway) then you should have no problem. You also should not have any need to set any value for `contentHeight`, unless you wish to use it for its stated purpose instead. Either way it has no effect on the height of individual rows.

N.B. If that isn't your problem, then you'll need to update your question with enough relevant code for us to be able to diagnose the exact issue. A screenshot of your problem might also be helpful.

Comment: Yes!

I was using the demo files supplied by Fullcalendar, and they had put eventLimit: true in there.

It's embarrassing, but I just didn't see that line in there.

I did do a lot of research and searching, but sometimes the toughest problems to solve are the easiest, since no one else ever had to ask.

Thank you for your help.  The heretofore unseen default functionality is indeed what I was seeking.